# Easy way to convert # of months into # of years and months in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

Is there an easy way in Groovy to convert months (ex: 58 months) into years and months.. 4 years, 10 months?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
def months = 58
println "${(months / 12) as int} years, ${months % 12} months"
```

It doesn't handle the edge cases like using singular for one year or one month, or omitting the years/months part in case they are zero.

As an alternative you could use a Java library like [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/), too.

Answer (score 2):

Basic concept, not really tied to any language:

```
58 / 12 = 4
58 % 12 = 10
```

Unless you are asking some sort of trick question? :-)